# Having problems installing Ubuntu

Tags: system-installation

I recently tried to install Ubuntu server on a Dell optiplex and the installer crashes and prompts a message similar to the one on the attached picture. I tried to install Debian and the installer also gets stuck on the network setup part. I have previously installed both Ubuntu and Debian on this computer and without any issue.
I would really appreciate some help.
Thanks

My setup:
Dell optiplex 7010
Intel i7 3770s
16GB ddr3 ram
1tb sata SSD drive
Ubuntu 22.04 LTS
Usb drive: SanDisk cruzer blade 32GB

[Error picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RFo7P.jpg)
[Full error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IabGp.jpg)
[Full error zoom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PXZ1N.jpg)

Comment: You have me confused it worked or it did not you have said both.

Comment: I have updated the post in order to provide more details. Sorry for the inconvenience

Comment: If it worked before and does not now is the computer broke?

Comment: It does boot to the already installed os (proxmox) which is essentially Debian

Comment: On the Full Error Report, you need to scroll down to the actual errors. Nothing in those images so far shows a problem.

Comment: Interpretation: You need to view the error report that was generated, what is visible in the image tells nothing more than the fact that the mishap was very early in the startup.

Answer (score -1):

I fixed it by using diskparted on a Windows installer to delete what g parted and other Linux partitioning tools couldn't. Then everything worked fine.
Thanks for all of the answers and sorry for the inconvenience.